# struct in C does not compile

Tags: c, struct, mingw

I have made the following code in C:

```
 1 |   #include <stdio.h>
 2 |   #include <stdlib.h>
 3 |   #include <time.h>
 4 |   
 5 |   typedef struct{
 6 |           int cod;
 7 |   } car;
 8 |   
 9 |   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
10 |   {
11 |     int i;
12 |     car store[10];
13 |     srand(time(NULL));
14 |     for (i=0;i<10;i++){
15 |         store[i].cod=rand();
16 |     }
17 |     system("PAUSE");
18 |     return 0;
19 |   }
```

The problem is that this code does not compile. The errors I got are:

```
 7  C:\Dev-Cpp\main.c [Warning] useless keyword or type name in empty declaration 
 7  C:\Dev-Cpp\main.c [Warning] unnamed struct/union that defines no instances 
15  C:\Dev-Cpp\main.c request for member `cod' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: Works in GCC-4.7.3 (MinGW 32). What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: There are no such errors in your code. Are you sure you posted the real code?

Comment: [For me, it compiles.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ddc1cadc322da27af0eea85e6258102a-138b2c0e84965803485951d209585b58)

Comment: Dev C++ 4.9 that is the version

Comment: Dev-C++ is fairly ancient, try [MinGW/MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started)

Comment: @Kninnug that version is indeed pretty ancient, but Dev-C++ itself lives on: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ and uses MinGW/MSYS

Comment: @stijn Ah, I didn't know about that version. It indeed does seem to use (MinGW) GCC-4.7.2.

Comment: maybe your compiler wants you to split it: struct {} car; typedef struct car;

Comment: also maybe it takes a standard flag, like old gcc, --std=c99

Comment: @Grady Player: When the struct has no tag, it cannot be split that way.

Comment: BTW, does it observe the file extension and compile it as C? Or does it compile it as C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the compiler you are using. I can only suggest adding a tag to your struct type

```
typedef struct car {
        int cod;
} car;
```

It won't require any changes in the rest of the code, but might help it to compile.